# passing a function with argument

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

JQuery:

```
alert_question ('Do you want it?', function(dialog){
                    // Do something
                }); 

var alert_question = function(question, yes_reaction_function(dialogItself))
{
    BootstrapDialog.show(
    {
        message: question,
        buttons: [
        {
            label: 'Yes',
            cssClass: 'btn-primary',
            action: yes_reaction_function (dialogItself)
```

I know it doesn't look like a good code. My goal is to write a generic function implementing dialog box and I've got no idea how to pass the success function.
As of now, I have an error UNEXPECTED TOKEN on the last line in the snippet above

Comment: Code shown isn't syntactically complete

Comment: closing parenthesis are missing can you please add complete code

Answer (score 0):

Based on you question below code you can try :

Html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.js"></script>
<div id="confirmDialog"></div>
<div id="div_input">
    <input type="button" id="1" value="1" onClick="javascript:confirmAction(updateButton, this.id)" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
    function confirmAction(onSuccessFunction, functionArg,alert_question)
    {
        var question = alert_question
        $('#confirmDialog').html(question);
        $('#confirmDialog').dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Confirm',
            width: 400,
            height: 150,
            buttons: {
                'Yes': function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    onSuccessFunction(functionArg);
                },
                'No': function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
        $("#confirmDialog").dialog('open');
    };
    function updateButton(buttonId)
    {
        alert(buttonId);
        var buttonHTML = '';
        if(buttonId == '1')
        {
            buttonHTML = "<input type='button' id='2' value='2' onClick='javascript:confirmAction(updateButton, this.id)' />";
        }
        else
        {
            buttonHTML = "<input type='button' id='1' value='1' onClick='javascript:confirmAction(updateButton, this.id)' />";
        }
        document.getElementById("div_input").innerHTML = buttonHTML;
    };
```